# Trying to find the perfect color for a readable font with a difficult multicolored background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, color-theory, font-recommendation

[image][image: Kwik history first wash**strong text**]

Trying to find the right color font that can be seen with this background image. Our color profiles is red, yellow, and black but if these will not work whats a good alternative? The image with the writing was chosen due to the less intense white that was washing out the yellow. I tried black and red but still have letters hard to read. the final image size is going to be 300x350 pixels so now I'm also worried about all the font being readable, making finding the right color even harder. If any of that makes since. I was going to post the work I did to the first image. But photoshop crashed and I didn't save so I started with the second image. Any tips, tricks or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you think yellow or red will be legible over this background? Can you post an example image with text over it?

Comment: I don't really get the question, the photo is black and white...any font color will work for it?

Comment: Hello Nicholas, welcome to GD.SE. Could you please post an example of what you have tried and why you are discontent with the results? You can [edit] this information into your question. That will enable us to help you way better. If you have questions about this site, have a look at the [help] to know how things work and how to write a good question. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Comment: How big will the text be relative to the image? Are you willing to darken the image a little bit to help the readability of the colored font? Any accessibility constraints your are trying to stay within?

Comment: I Hope the updated photo can help illustrate my problem. The first image the white in the tress and the building along with the dark limbs were making it hard to get any color to be clearly legible. the new image was chosen as a background due to sentimental reasons to the owner. It has her late father driving the car through his first touchless car wash. I hope you can see my issues with color still in this new image how the yellow at the top is washed out and the red on certain spaces is hard to read. the final size for the website it will be advertised on is 300x350 pixels.

Comment: Any ideas on what to change or how I should edit the background image would be greatly appreciated. It's been awhile since I've used photoshop but it's starting to come back to me so not to sound to dumb, but any ideas or tips put in layman's terms would be helpful. Or at least better understood since I'm still trying to remember everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rethink the design.

The photo is interesting but there's no single color that is going to make the text "pop" in itself. The design needs to implement *something* to decrease the prominence of the photo overall.

A couple random options......

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow I really need to step up my design and thoughts I wish I could do some things like that to really try and make it pop.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new layer, choose a white-to-transparent gradient. Start at the top with white and end with transparent somewhere in the middle of the image, below where the text ends. Hold down the shift key to constrain the gradient to 90º. You may have to apply the gradient several times to get it in the correct position. Then adjust the transparency of the layer until you can see enough of the image at the top to get the idea, and still be able to read the text.

Answer (score 0):

**The words are what are important.**

That being said, if you can, I would first darken the entire image.

Then, I'd just use white text over some of the darker parts of the image. The placement is up to you. In your example, I'd put it over the dark trees.

If that doesn't work, another option is to reduce the opacity of the background image, and just use a solid black, with the red for emphasis if you need.

Push comes to shove, you can use white text with a black border. On second thought, this would make the text seem older, which seems to be thematic.

Good luck =)